# Convert Stata Forvalues loop to R

Tags: r, loops, stata

I would like to run a loop over a series of variables (Change_1 to Change_12) to check if they meet certain conditions. Based on that, I want to create dummies. How do I do this loop in R?

```
 generate newvariable=0
 forvalues i = 1/12 {  
 replace newvariable=1 if Change_`i'==1 | Change_`i'== 6| Change_`i'==9
    }
```

Comment: In Stata that could be one line (no loop) as  something like`egen newvar = anymatch(Change_*), values(1 6 9)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# generate a data.frame of fake data to match your problem
C <- 12
R <- 100
data <- matrix(sample(1:9, size=C*R, replace=TRUE), nrow=R, ncol=C)
df <- as.data.frame(data)
names(df) <- paste0("change_",1:C)

# create a new variable
df$newvar = 0

# replace each row of newvar with a 1 if 
# the value for change_i is 1, 6, or 9
for(i in 1:C) {
    who_to_replace <- df[[paste0("change_",i)]] %in% c(1,6,9)
    df[who_to_replace, "newvar"] <- 1
}
```